# FlashBuilder 4.6/Adobe Air - TextInput duplicating letters

Tags: air, adobe, flash-builder, flash-builder4.5

I am using FB 4.6 to develop an App for both Android and iOS. I have run into a situation with text input fields where on some occasions, when pressing a single letter will actually add multiple characters of the same letter to the text input field. When I attempt to add the next letter, it will duplicate the existing text in the text field and add it on to the text. For example, entering the word, "Adobe" may end up looking something like "AAddAAddoobbAAddoobbee". This issue seems to be isolated to Android.

Here's an example of one of my input fields:

```
<s:TextInput id="email_txt" left="20" top="47" width="316" prompt="Player's Email"    restrict="^'&quot;" focusIn="email_txt_focusInHandler(event)" focusOut="email_txt_focusOutHandler(event)" skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.StageTextInputSkin" softKeyboardType="email" />
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Thanks, in advance, for any and all replies.

Comment: The code that is causing the issue is listed in the original question. Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that this is caused by the buggy stage text feature. The problems I've seen on IOS could be resolved by changing the skin to one that does not use stage text: "spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin". Not much help, but you can at least confirm that this is the culprit.

Comment: can we see the **StageTextInputSkin** skin and **email_txt_focusInHandler(event), email_txt_focusOutHandler(event)** function code?

Comment: I have the same bug with a classic TextField on Android I have open a new bug report on this over at [https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3504577](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3504577)